# Capacitance divider of Colpitts Oscillator

Tags: oscillator, vco

For the following Colpitts Oscillator, Why does employing the capacitance divider up-converts the source impedance of transistor by a factor of **(1+C2/C1)<sup>2</sup>**

[image: colpitts]

Comment: currents step up and voltages step down, thus Ratio squared.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf why _currents step up and voltages step down_ ?

Comment: I think the whole page is somewhat ambiguous and misses fundamental aspects of the Colpitts design.

Comment: At best they have C1 and C2 swapped in the formula.

Comment: to understand why the stepup, stepdown, FIRST understand why a PI network (PI resonator) also provides stepup, stepdown.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to note about the Colpitts circuit is that it's not a pure capacitive divider, it's a resonant circuit containing two capacitors in series, as well as an inductor.

*At the resonant frequency*, and for *a limited range of component ratios*, the circuit can be redrawn into an equivalent circuit using (amongst other things) an autotransformer, with the turns ratio having the squared form as described (maybe with C1 and C2 swapped, not sure, several people think so). Outside the range of relevant ratios, the equivalent circuit includes things like negative capacitance, which is obviously non-physical.

Does this restriction to a limited range invalidate the general conclusion? No, because a Colpitts Oscillator will only work within a restricted range of values. You cannot arbitrarily set C1 to 1% of C2 and expect it to work.

Comment: For ex if C2 grows, but C1 stays, the factor increases. The resonance frequency doesn't get affected when C1 <<C2. Finally The load impedance of the tank can be made as big as wanted by increasing C2. Really?

Comment: @user287001 For a successful Colpits design, C1 and C2 are within an order of magnitude of each other, so the limit of C1<<C2 is never met. Increasing capacitor values reduces tank impedance. You can do it without limit in a simulator, but in any practical situation you have to know what the other components require and design accordingly. I have worked with VCOs with extremely low impedances, 500MHz, inductor a few mm of FR4 track, 100pFs of varactors, when needed for very low noise. I've added a few words to head off the silly extension to arbitrary ratios.

Comment: and still sure that C1 and C2 aren't swapped?

Comment: @user287001 C1 and C2 swapped? Maybe, I haven't bothered to look that closely. If somebody wants to find a colpits diagram that shows the equivalent circuit with the Cs in the right positions, and the expression for the series C that can go negative, I'd be beholden to them.

Comment: Now some righteous and highly relevant  speak: Please don't write guesses as an answer, guesses belong in comments, with a question mark, if at all.

Comment: In most LC Colpitts of this type, **C1 > C2** to achieve the impedance up-scaling described. Perhaps the author was thinking more of *capacitive reactance* ratio (I'm being generous)?